# Master user on RDS postgres can not grant schema privileges to new user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin-4

I have around 5 test postgres databases on a RDS instance.  Till date all have been created and run using the `Master_user` (created at the instance creation).

I am now trying to create 5 new users and Grant ALL privilages for each of the databases respectively.  I tried Pgadmin4 Grant wizard, but I get permission denied error for any grant option.  `Grant ALL` doesnt work, and `Grant Create, Insert` etc also doesn't work.  What could be the issue??

Comment: is master_user a member of  `rds_superuser`?..

Comment: Yes. In PGadmin4 master_user => properties => membership => in Roles, I do see `rds_superuser`and I can also check the mark for `Select the checkbox for roles to include WITH ADMIN OPTION.`  Then I right click on  `test_db1` => Grant Wizard =>select single schema (or all schemas) => select Grantee as 'test_user1` => select single privilege like Insert (or select All Privs) => Finish => Get `Error: Permission denied for schema *****`

Comment: I remeber you can definetely grant on relation if you are a relation owner...

Comment: I just tried it while I wrote above comment.  I also did this through the query. couldnt grant all or grant to specific schema or tables.  There has been no other user on the RDS instance since it was created.  Its just the single user and its a master_user.

Comment: then I think its time to write to aws support?..

Comment: finally decided to sit and try myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ended up backing up all the databases with `--no-owner --no-acl`, renaming the databases and creating new ones with new owners.  restored each backup with each owner and achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

let's assume we connected to db as rds_superuser, so then we need do steps:

1. grant relation owner to rds_superuser (tobe able to "become" it)
2. become the owner
3. grant

Eg.:

```
rds_superuser@rds_db> grant schema_owner to rds_superuser ;
GRANT ROLE
rds_superuser@rds_db> set role schema_owner;
SET
rds_superuser@rds_db> grant select on all tables in schema schema_name to new_user;
GRANT
rds_superuser@rds_db> reset role;
RESET
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the main database that was created with the instance as a template, so that the main user will have full access to it. I think they are just trying to limit people from creating several DBs on the same RDS..